# A famous Integral from Cauchy deriving, how?

Tags: complex

A example of calculating line integrals in the complex plane

`Integrate[Cos[2*b*x]/E^x^2, {x, 0, Infinity}]` = $\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi } e^{-b^2}$
( this is the famous integral from Cauchy)

$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\cos  (2 b x)}{e^{x^2}} \, dx = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi } e^{-b^2}$

Look at the integral of $f(z)\text{:=}e^{-z^2}$
on the route
It consists of 4 parts C1,C2,C3,C4

First step is how to write different from this contourintegral in z notation to (u,v) notation symbolically in MMA : $\int f(z) \, dz=\int (I v+u)(dx+I dy)$  ? (how to get this expression in MMA, as it is written in example text, but don't know the derivation of it : (dx+ I*dy) )

u and v are functions of x and y  : u(x,y and v(x,y)

**EDIT**
Fill in z= x+Iy  in function definition f[z_]

step 1

`z = x + I*y`

`f[z_] := E^(-z^2)`

`f[z_] := Cos[2*x*y]/(E^z^2*E^y^2) - I*Sin[2*x*y]`

step 2

Now split f[z_] in part 1 into  a real part and imaginair part as functions of u(x,y) and v(x,y).

`u[x_, y_] = ComplexExpand[Re[f[x + I*y]]]` = `E^y^2*Cos[2*x*y])/E^x^2`

`v[x_, y_] = ComplexExpand[Im[f[x + I*y]]]` = `-E^(-x^2))*E^y^2*Sin[2*x*y`

`f[z_] := u[x, y] + I*v[x, y]`

Now integrate this f[z]

Step 3

[image: route]

After integrating f[z] , integrate over **C1..C4 contour**,and get a integral I-tot: I-1(real) + I-2 (imaginair)

I-tot = 0 ( Cauchy contour =0 )
Note: The real and imaginair part of I-tot = 0

So I-1 = 0 and consists of 3 integrals

You can rearrange these 3 integrals: (I-1)( with some more bounds switching) until the following integral emerges:

$\int_0^a e^{-x^2} \, dx=e^{b^2} \int_0^a e^{-x^2} \cos (2 b x) \, dx-e^{-a^2} \int_0^b e^{y^2} \sin (2 a y) \, dy$  **(1)**

`Integrate[E^(-x^2), {x, 0, a}] = E^b^2*Integrate[Cos[2*b*x]/E^x^2, {x, 0, a}] -  Integrate[E^y^2*Sin[2*a*y], {y, 0, b}]/E^a^2`

[image: chance square]

a-> infinity ..square.

Square turned into an infinitely wide strip of height b
**What happens to the integrals (see **(1)**) ?**

note: `Integrate[E^(-x^2), {x, 0, a}]` ...This integral is half of the Gauss integral for the normal distribution.

Comment: Questions should contain a minimal effort from you.  There are many questions on this site related to the path integrals.  Even at a minimal level I cannot see how this question is related to *Mathematica*.

Comment: Integrate[f[u], {u, 0, a}] + I Integrate[f[a + v I], {v, 0, b}] - 
 Integral[f[u + I b], {u, 0, a}] - I Integral[f[I v], {v, 0, b}]

Comment: @Artes, i made a start , see EDIT in question

Comment: @Daniel Huber, i go a step back and try first calculate this integral for f[z]

Comment: If this question is about how to compute the integral in Mathematica, the answer is given in the question, `Integrate[Cos[2*b*x]/E^x^2, {x, 0, Infinity}]`.  If the question is about how to derive the integral mathematically, it belongs on math.SE.

Comment: @MichaelE2 , its about how to derive this integral with MMA in steps. 
Example: in step 1 (see question) in i must do a substitution in f[z} and try to get a Cos and Sin in the endresult.

Comment: I have to guess at what the points of steps 1 and 2 are. Please clarify.

Comment: @Michael E2 , step 1 and 2 leads to a integral in step 3( with some boundry adjustments) and letting boundry a, go to infinity gives  again a integral :(int=int)
This int = int  , simplified  gives the famous Cauchy integral

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Second answer. Now i got, what you realy want.

The full contour integral for differentiable f[z] is zero. You get the desired integral, if you take -integral over C2,C3  and C4 and let a go to infinity.

```
f[z_] = E^(-z^2) Cos[2 b z]

f[x + I y]

u[x_, y_] = 
 f[x + I y] // ComplexExpand[Re@#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] &

v[x_, y_] = 
 f[x + I y] // ComplexExpand[Im@#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] &

ii = -(I Integrate[u[a, y] + i v[a, y], {y, 0, b}] + 
    Integrate[u[x, b] + I v[x, b], {x, a, 0}] + 
    I Integrate[u[0, y] + I v[0, y], {y, b, 0}])

Limit[ii, a -> Infinity]


(*   1/2 E^-b^2 Sqrt[Pi]   *)
```

Comment: I added some more information to the question in order to be capable to follow the prove idea exactly in MMA?
I must also add the illustrations made in MMA by me ( replace in the e question)
There is some MMA code syntax in your answer what has to be studied by me.

Comment: 14, looks you follow about the same prove idea as in the question.

Comment: Akku 14, thanks for your help. Get some more insight now in how to use commands

Answer (score 4):

Add inaginary part to integrand, integrate, and delete imaginary part again.

```
f = Cos[2*b*x]/E^x^2;

f2 = f /. Cos[2 b x] -> (Cos[2 b x] + I Sin[2 b x]) // TrigToExp

(*   E^(2 I b x - x^2)   *)

int[x_] = Integrate[f2, x, Assumptions -> x > 0]

(*   -(1/2) I E^-b^2 Sqrt[Pi] Erfi[b + I x]   *)

Limit[int[x], x -> Infinity] - 
   Limit[int[x], x -> 0, Direction -> -1] // 
  ComplexExpand[Re@#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & // 
 Simplify[#, b \[Element] Reals] &

(*   1/2 E^-b^2 Sqrt[Pi]   *)
```

Or

```
Integrate[f2, {x, 0, Infinity}] // Re // 
 Simplify[#, Element[b, Reals]] &

(*   1/2 E^-b^2 Sqrt[Pi]   *)
```

Comment: @thanks Akku 14, for showing more ways to calculate this famous integral

Answer (score 4):

I don't know yet what is wanted, whether to reproduce Cauchy's argument, whatever it was for has not been given, or to mimic some other argument.  Some sort of argument based on paths seems to be called for, and for Mathematica to do the computation(s).

**Method 1: Simplest, and yet mysteriously dissatisfying(?)**

Plug it into `Integrate` to integrate over the path $\text{Im}(z)=0,\ \text{Re}(z)\ge0$, and see if it works:

```
Integrate[Cos[2*b*x]/E^x^2, {x, 0, Infinity}]
(*  1/2 E^-b^2 Sqrt[π]  *)
```

Violà.

**Method 2**

It's fairly clear that multiplying the integrand by the constant `1/2 E^b^2` allows the simplification:

```
Simplify[
 1/2 E^b^2 Cos[2*b*x]/E^x^2 == 1/4 E^-(x - I b)^2 + 1/4 E^-(x + I b)^2]
(*  True  *)
```

The imaginary parts of the two terms of $\frac{1}{4} e^{-(x-i b)^2}+\frac{1}{4} e^{-(x+i b)^2}$ cancel so the integral is twice the real part of the integral of either term. Plugging into `Integrate` again yields the answer sought:

```
(2 Simplify[Re[Integrate[1/4 E^-z^2, {z, I b, Infinity}]], 
  b ∈ Reals])/(1/2 E^b^2)
(*  1/2 E^-b^2 Sqrt[π]  *)
```

**Method 3**

Again working from $\frac{1}{4} e^{-(x-i b)^2}+\frac{1}{4} e^{-(x+i b)^2}$,
to get some path-integral hocus-pocus, if simpler approaches are to be shunned,
we can integrate each term separately, substitute $x \mapsto z \pm ib$ to get the integral $\int \frac14 e^{-z^2}\,dz$ over rays along $z=\pm ib$, $\text{Re}(z)\ge0$.  These two are equivalent to integrals over polygonal paths that go from $z=\pm ib$ to the origin to infinity along the positive $x$-axis. Again plug into `Integrate` and there you go:

```
(1/(1/2 E^b^2)) *
 (Integrate[1/4 E^-z^2, {z, I b, 0}] + 
  Integrate[1/4 E^-z^2, {z, -I b, 0}] + 
  2 Integrate[1/4 E^-z^2, {z, 0, Infinity}])
(*  1/2 E^-b^2 Sqrt[π]  *)
```

**Method 4**

Maybe this is what is meant, since it follows some of the paths in the figure:

```
Integrate[Cos[2*b*z]/E^z^2, {z, a, a + I b}, Assumptions -> a > 0] +
  Integrate[ Cos[2*b*z]/E^z^2, {z, a + I b, I b}, 
   Assumptions -> a > 0] +
  Integrate[Cos[2*b*z]/E^z^2, {z, I b, 0}]
(*
1/4 E^-b^2 Sqrt[π] (-2 + Erf[a] + Erf[a + 2 I b] + Erfc[a - I b] +
     Erfc[a + I b]) - 
 1/4 E^-b^2 Sqrt[π] (Erf[a] + Erf[a + 2 I b] - I Erfi[2 b]) - 
 1/4 I E^-b^2 Sqrt[π] Erfi[2 b]
*)

Limit[%, a -> Infinity]
(*  -(1/2) E^-b^2 Sqrt[π]  *)
```

Actually, the above may be done more succintly by specifying the entire path in a single `Integrate`:

```
Limit[
 Integrate[Cos[2*b*z]/E^z^2, {z, a, a + I b, I b, 0}, 
  Assumptions -> a > 0],
 a -> Infinity]
(*  -(1/2) E^-b^2 Sqrt[π]  *)
```

Comment: Oops, I forgot that I translated the path in method 2, too.  Or I copied the wrong code.

Comment: @Micheal E2, thanks for your calculations, there are many ways to solve this as it seems. 
I added some more information to the question in order to be capable to follow the prove idea exactly in MMA.

Comment: @Micheal E2, I have a hard time deciding between the answers given which one best answers my question?
I need more time for this to study the answers.

Comment: @Micheal E2, Example : Is there an easy way of drawing a part of a circle used in a complex contour?
Was a question from me, has six excellent answers : must also choose yet the best answers i like.

Comment: @Micheal E2, I still think I choose the best answer of Akku 14, because it follows more the reasoning as I described in the question.
Thanks again for your answers.

Comment: @Micheal E2, thanks again to come up with 4 methods for calculating this integral.
Also very helpful to get used for me doing this sort of  integrals

Comment: @janhardo You're welcome. I guess from the accepted answer you wanted the code in terms of the parts `u[]` and `v[]`. I thought your problem was with setting up `Integrate[]`. Since the integral is given both in terms of `f` and in terms of  `u` and `v` in the question already, I thought it didn't matter which expression was the integrand, since they equivalent.